# Handling null JSON response in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json

Here's the snippet of code where I get a JSON response :

```
app.controller('apiController', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Kansas+City&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&appid=f6b7081abd94e66273817ed6b5ce95c7").then(function(response) {
    $scope.myData = response.data.list;
});
});
```

What are some of the best practices to handle say an empty/garbage/null JSON response?

Answer (score 2):

By using  `AngularJS` `$httpProvider.interceptors` we can handle request and response globally.Here I am adding code for response only. 
First create one `angular factory`  e.g.

```
myModule.factory('myResponseInterceptors', function ($q) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            // do something on success
        if(response.data == null)
       {
        // Do what ever you want to do 
       }
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            // do something on error
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
```

And add this factory into `$httpProvider` on your main module `config` section

```
myModule.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myResponseInterceptors');
});
```

`AngularJs` `httpPromise`  response object has following properties

**data** – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
**status** – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
**headers** – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
**config** – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
**statusText** – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, like this:

```
app.controller('apiController', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Kansas+City&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&appid=f6b7081abd94e66273817ed6b5ce95c7").then(function(response) {
    if(response.data){
        $scope.myData = response.data.list;
    }else{
        // TODO: your data is null or undefined
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best answer but you can handle it in the following way,

`angular.isUndefined(val) || val === null`

```
app.controller('apiController', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/dailyq=Kansas+City&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&appid=f6b7081abd94e66273817ed6b5ce95c7").then(function(response) {
   $scope.myData = response.data.list;
   if(angular.isUndefined($scope.myData) || $scope.myData === null)
   {
     //Type an user friendly error msg for the end user and show on view
      $scope.errorMsg = "Sorry...the list is empty".
     // handle hide and show of this error msg whenever $scope.mydata is undefined or null.
   }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add this check

```
if(response.data) {
  if(response.data.list) {
    $scope.myData=response.data.list;
  }
}
```